# How to make my electron app install-able on Linux

Tags: linux, electron, publish, apt, snapcraft

Recently made build an application using Electron Framework. It is very basic. Now I have built it for Linux and published it to snap-store.

Now I want the application to be install-able by the `apt-get` command.

Is there any such way that I can do this?